# Email batches via AWS SES, ideas?

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services, email, cron, amazon-ses

I have an SaaS application where each paying customer may have thousands of members they may want to send emails to every now and then.

For now, simple BCC sending via AWS SES have done the trick, but now I am looking at sending personalized emails so I must be able to send the emails one by one.

SES does not have any queue system as per my knowledge, you must make an API call per email. In short, it takes forever to send a batch (my limit is 14 per second), and the user cannot close the page while it is executing (even AJAX calls stop executing if you leave the page, am I right?).

I was thinking of building a system where I store the emails in a database table and then either:

1) Use a CRON that executes every 5 seconds or so, grab a few emails and send them.

2) Execute an AJAX script each 5 seconds that grabs the emails for said logged in customer in a batch ONLY and send them out, but again, if the customer logs out while it executes chances are that specific a batch is interrupted (the remaining ones would still keep sending the next time the customer logs in).

Does any have any better ideas? Or, which of the two above would be preferred?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use templates and the SendBulkTemplatedEmail endpoint that AWS introduced a few months ago: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/ses/introducing-email-templates-and-bulk-sending/.

That way you can send up to 50 personalized emails with a single SES API call. So 700 with 14 calls.

You shouldn't consider queuing them up in a user's browser and sending them by making a series of AJAX requests though. You should only send one Ajax request to start a job. In most server-side languages (any I can think of) you can respond to an HTTP request and still continue doing processing after responding. You can also implement a progress checker in a multitude of ways.

Comment: But, if I call a page using AJAX, won't it stop executing if a visitor leaves the page? Or will it still execute until it's done?

Comment: @RobertBenedetto That depends on your server-side language and code. Based on your assumption of that I think you are using PHP, in which case one way you might achieve it with a single Ajax call would look something like this: 1) Read user input 2) Start a separate process for sending the emails 3) Respond to the Ajax call with the status (started successfully or not).

Comment: One down side of this approach is, you loose application portability. Meaning, you won't be able to plugin a different email service without a code change.  I'd recommend using a corn based approach if you are concerned about application portability.

Comment: @PaulPro I'm using C# (.Net), so I guess a threading call might be the trick?

Comment: Actually, I guess I could do the whole thing without AJAX by just using running it on another thread? The thread will still execute even if the user navigates to another page right?

Comment: @Anuruddha all cron does is the scheduling of processes. If you want to run a process at a non-predetermined timed based on user actions there is no point on using it.

Comment: @RobertBenedetto Yeah, you don't need AJAX at all, I just assumed that you were using an AJAX request from the user to let your server know to send the emails. You can start the thread any way you like. I'm not very familiar with C# but I assume the thread will continue to run after you have sent a response to the user. So it would look similar to PHP except starting a new thread in step 2 instead of an entire process.

Comment: @RobertBenedetto What I meant to suggest is to avoid AWS SES templating API and use SMTP based approach along with a cron job, saving the application portability.

Comment: @RobertBenedetto Then if you want to implement progress checks you can have the thread store state somewhere (in a db?) about how far it has gotten and you could poll that state with AJAX (or use server-sent events, websockets, etc). That way your user can be informed about how many have sent and notified when all have been sent (assuming they haven't logged out).

Comment: Anuruddha my system is already hosted on AWS and uses several of their other services, so I don't mind using SES for this as well.

@Paulpro I like your idea of saving progress in DB, will definitely look any that.

Comment: @Paulpro what about the spending limits? I have a rate of 14. Does that mean I can only do 14 recipients (destinations) per call? And angry that I must sleep the thread for a second?

Comment: @RobertBenedetto I guess it would be affected by that. Have you already tried contacting AWS to [increase you limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/increase-sending-limits.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a cronjob that sends to the SES SMTP server. This way you can personalize the emails and also control how many emails to send. Your cronjob can sleep in between each batch of emails.

Answer (score 0):

You can use celery to run background job. A user submits a request on a webpage which starts a background job through celery. The background job take care of sending emails. Once sending emails is completed, inform the user by email.

http://www.celeryproject.org/

Comment: celery? Have a link or something? What’s that?